# SCOM Service UniMonitor with Dynamic AlertSeverity

Tags: service, monitor, scom, management-pack

I have defined a UnitMonitor of type CheckNTServiceStateMonitorType. The AlertSeverity of this Monitor depends on an attribute of the class being monitored, so it is dynamically specified.
However, I I could find no way to set the AlertSeverity dynamically. For instances:

```
<AlertSettings>
     <AlertSeverity>
         $Target/Property[MyMonitoredClass]/AlertSeverity$
     <AlertSeverity>
</AlertSettings>
```

Is there any way to  accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it for a Unit Monitor. Such feature is only available for Rules.

Cheers
Max

Comment: Thanks for the info